# Secure connection in localhost tomcat not working

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, ssl

I am working on spring web app using maven. I am trying to make localhost a secure connection.I am using tomcat server. I used this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbyb/index.html) for creating my own CA and added it to JVM.
This is what I added in pom.xml.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <path>/security</path>
            <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="200" scheme="https" secure="true" keystoreFile="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.71.x86_64/jre/lib/security/cacerts.jks" keystorePass="security"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />

        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I went to the link:https://localhost:8443 . But no app is running on that port. Could someone please help?

Comment: Did you install the SSL certificate??  You also dont need to specify connectors here, you can do that in server.xml of tomcat. Also, have you instructed your webapp to use https?? It can be easily done in spring-security.

Comment: Also you need to declare http and https ports so the webapp knows which port to use. Please paste your securityApplicationContext.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Go to sever.xml and add following xml

```
 <Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" 
clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="{path}/mycer.cert" keystorePass="{password}"/>
     <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
        <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

1. first you want to create one CA certificate
2. you can use java key tool for certificate creation
3. store that certificate on your server .
4. add connector config with in your tomcat server.xml
5. you should provide certificate path and password that given
6. restart server

if any problem for restarting comment stack trace

http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-support-ssl-or-https/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a connector in `servlet.xml` file.

```
<Connector
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           port="8443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Replace the keystore file path and the password with the ones you have.

Refer https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html.